# How to search by metadata using REST API

Tags: metabox, rest-api

I have a custom post type like this:

```
register_post_type('horario_busao', [
    'labels' => [
        'name' => 'Horário Busões',
        'singular_name' => 'Horário Busão'
    ],
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true
]);
```

And it contains a metadata `city`, which I update it this way:

```
return update_post_meta($postId, 'city', $city);
```

So I'm fetching it by the endpoint `/wp-json/wp/v2/horario_busao`. As I see in the documentation, it only contain the query param `search`.

How can I search it by metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I search it by metadata?

*As far as I know, there's no standard/built-in way of doing that (for the time being). But with **custom coding**, you can make it possible:*

You can append a `city` to the query string:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/horario_busao?city=London
```

And then use the [`rest_{$this->post_type}_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) filter to set the meta key/value pair which would be passed to `WP_Query`. Here's an example:

```
add_filter( 'rest_horario_busao_query', function( $args, $request ){
    if ( $city = $request->get_param( 'city' ) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'city';
        $args['meta_value'] = $city;
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Wow! it just works!! thank you so much

Comment: Is the `$args` a object like `WP_Query`? can I filter by multiple metadata?

Comment: Yes, the `$args` is the same parameters you would use when making post queries using `new WP_Query( $args )` or `get_posts( $args )`. So you can use the `meta_query` parameter to make multiple meta queries - or to filter by multiple metadatas. (Btw, sorry for the late reply..)

Comment: Thank you for the clean explanation!